# Identical Functions in a Domain

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Problem statement:
If f<sub>1</sub>(z) and f<sub>2</sub>(z) are analytic in a domain D and equal at a sequence of points z<sub>n</sub> in D that converges in D, show that f<sub>1</sub>(z)=f<sub>2</sub>(z).

I'm not clear on this - I understand that since both are analytic in D, so they both have a Taylor series in D, but the convergent set of points doesn't have to match up.  I came up with what I think is a counterexample:

f<sub>1</sub>(z)= sin(1/z), f<sub>2</sub>(z)= -sin(1/z)

D: z = (0, 1)

z<sub>n</sub> = 1/(n*pi), n positive integers

In this domain,

f<sub>1</sub>(z)=f<sub>2</sub>(z) for all z<sub>n</sub>

In the example, I only use real numbers - not sure if that's an issue.  The sum of the sequence doesn't actually converge but that's not part of the problem statement - in any case, it could be substituted with 1/(2<sup>n</sup>*pi).

Any assistance (including pointing out whatever flaws in the counterexample) would be welcome.

Comment: You have been around for almost eight years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your counterexample: first, domains must be open, which your choice of the real interval $(0, 1)$ is not. This isn't an issue since in fact your functions are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

The bigger and much more significant issue is that the sequence $z_n$ must have an accumulation point *in $D$*; your proposed sequence $z_n$ has accumulation point $0$ which is not and cannot be in $D$. The proof involves the Taylor expansion around the accumulation point so this hypothesis is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that, in your example, $D=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. But then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n\pi}=0\notin D$. So, you did not create a counterexample; remember that the statement has the hypothesis that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\in D$.

Comment: Thanks, pointing out that the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\$ must be in D clarified that.

Comment: And I don't know why the MathJax didn't work in the above comment.  I hadn't realized MathJax was mandatory, so didn't mess with it - the results seemed legible enough without it.